# One time run function in wpf project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Is there a property in WPF where we can define a set of functions that run only once after installation of the WPF project? I was also wondering if we could define variables that kept the value on each run of the project?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at Settings of your project. Right click on the project and click on `Properties` then navigate to `Settings` there you can define variables. You can define the type of variable, scope and a default value. If you want to run a function once you can have boolean variable that goes to True if you run the function. Remember to set the scope according to your needs.